# Android query about onClick and android control flow

Tags: java, android

I am a beginner android programmer and I have this question.

I have a class as follows...

```
import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.DatePicker;

public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    private int year;
    private int month;
    private int day;

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
                AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK, this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        this.setYear(year);
        this.setMonth(month);
        this.setDay(day);
        System.out.println(day+""+month+""+year);
        // Do something with the date chosen by the user
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public int getMonth() {
        return month;
    }

    public void setMonth(int month) {
        this.month = month;
    }

    public int getDay() {
        return day;
    }

    public void setDay(int day) {
        this.day = day;
    }
}
```

In my main activity, I have a button with a listener and when I press it, it calls this class and brings up the dialog box/date picker as follows:

```
setDoBButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                DatePickerFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
                newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
            }
        });
```

My problem is, Once I click the button and the dialog box comes out, after I set my date and `onDateSet` is called, I cant use my getters the assign the dates to any variables in my mainactivity because the `onclick` is not waiting for me to finish setting the date in the dialog box.

Eg, if my listener was like this...

```
    setDoBButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    DatePickerFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
                    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
                    int x = newFragment.getDay();
                }
            });
```

It wouldnt work because the dialog box would show and then `getDay` would instantly be called because its in the `onclick` but the day hasnt been set in the dialog box. So how can I work around this?

Many thanks.

Comment: you need another object to be the DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener so that it can receive the event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Interface.

Define a interface in `DatePickerFragment`. Implement the interface in your activity class and use the same.

Check the topic under **Communicating with Activity**.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Example:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements DatePickerFragment.TheListener{

    Button b;
    TextView tv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        b= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        tv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                DialogFragment picker = new DatePickerFragment();
                picker.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void returnDate(String date) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        tv.setText(date);
    }

}
```

DatePickerFragment

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    TheListener listener;

public interface TheListener{
    public void returnDate(String date);
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Use the current date as the default date in the picker
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
listener = (TheListener) getActivity(); 

// Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
}

@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(year, month, day);

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String formattedDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());
if (listener != null) 
{
  listener.returnDate(formattedDate); // instead of date set the day

}

}
}
```

In the above example you have interface in DaterPicker

```
 public interface TheListener{
    public void returnDate(String date);
 }
```

Then

```
 listener.returnDate(formattedDate);
```

Then you implement the listener in your activity class

```
 implements DatePickerFragment.TheListener
```

You implement the method

```
  @Override
    public void returnDate(String date) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        tv.setText(date); // date is available here
    }
```

Comment: My mind just got blown. Thanks alot for this answer, it makes so much sense but I would have never been able to come up with it :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a method called assign variables or something like that
and on the `onclick` call that method

```
setDoBButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                DatePickerFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
                newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
                assign_variables();
            }
        });

private void assign_variables(){
    int x = newFragment.getDay();
}
```

**OR**

Create a `static class variable` like `go_on`

```
private static final boolean go_on = true;
```

and now in you `onclick` add an infinite loop

```
setDoBButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                DatePickerFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
                newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
                while(go_on){}
            }
        });
```

Then do your assignment as you want

```
int x = newFragment.getDay();
int y = newFragment.getTime();
go_on = false; //and set the boolean to false
```

now it will break the while loop and you get what you assigned what you want

**NOTE: Just see to it that you don't end in some deadlock or ANR error**